# How is file upload handled in HTTP?

Tags: apache, http, webserver, file-upload

I am curious to know how webservers handle file uploads.

Is the entire file sent as a single chunk? Or is it streamed into the webserver - which puts it together and saves it in a temp folder for PHP etc. to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of following the encoding rules so that one can easily decode (parse) it. Read on the [specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) about `multipart-form/data` encoding (the one which is required in HTML based file uploads using `input type="file"`).

Generally the parsing is done by the server side application itself. The webserver only takes care about streaming the bytes from the one to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

It's streamed to answer that question, but see this [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) describes the mechanism.